# Pass date parameter from crystal into stored procedure then convert to decimal in where clause

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report I have rewritten to use a stored procedure instead of multiple different tables.  The report is based on a date parameter.  The actual value I'll compare that with in the where clause of my stored procedure is a decimal.

My question is:  After I pass a date parameter from Crystal into a stored procedure - how do I then cast this date value into a decimal format so I can filter on this field.  (SQL)

Supplemental info:  The value is in a decimal format because Sage Software creates their date field in this way.

*I've tried casting as a varchar, substring and numeric prior - not working for me - so if you could please be as specific as possible or provide an example of how I'm supposed to do this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Decimal means is it in seconds?

Comment: .00 is always the decimal value

Comment: I think this may be the ticket but am still working with it:

Comment: (FROMDATE SMALLDATETIME, -- = '2015-06-28'
 TODATE SMALLDATETIME) --= '2015-07-04'
AS
DECLARE FROM AS DECIMAL(9,0)
DECLARE TO AS DECIMAL(9,0)
SET FROM = CAST(STR(DATEPART(YEAR, FROMDATE),4) + REPLACE(STR(DATEPART(MONTH, FROMDATE), 2), ' ', '0') + REPLACE(STR(DATEPART(DAY, FROMDATE), 2), ' ', '0') AS DECIMAL(9,0))
SET TO = CAST(STR(DATEPART(YEAR, TODATE),4) + REPLACE(STR(DATEPART(MONTH, TODATE), 2), ' ', '0') + REPLACE(STR(DATEPART(DAY, TODATE), 2), ' ', '0') AS DECIMAL(9,0))
where UPH.TRANSDATE >= FROM AND UPH.TRANSDATE < TO

Answer (score 0):

You're not just going to be able to cast a date into a decimal. First, you're going to have to do some sort of conversion to get it into a number. Probably by using `DateDiff()`. For example, if what that decimal REALLY represents is number of seconds since the epoch, you'd need to do this:

```
DateDiff("s", #1/1/1970#, parameter)
```

Then, you could take the output from `DateDiff()` and cast that into a decimal. But casting from a date to a decimal is just impossible; one is a complex data structure, the other is a base type.

Comment: After much trying and help from both of our DBA's - below is a copy of how we resolved the issue - in case anyone else out there may appreciate knowing:

Answer (score 0):

Below is the resolution we came up with - sharing for anyone else out there who may benefit.

*The naming conventions used below seem silly but I did it this way because I was rewriting a crystal - table based -report and I didn't want to have to start from scratch so I named fields easily recognizable within the proc and used the "Set Data Source Location" to update each table to use the stored proc field - saved tons of time doing it this way!

```
( @FROMDATE SMALLDATETIME, -- = '2015-06-28'
 @TODATE SMALLDATETIME) --= '2015-07-04'

 --@FROMDATE DECIMAL(9,0),
 --@TODATE DECIMAL(9,0) 
AS
--SET DECLARATIONS
DECLARE @FROM AS DECIMAL(9,0)
DECLARE @TO AS DECIMAL(9,0)

--SET VARIABLES
SET @FROM = CAST(STR(DATEPART(YEAR, @FROMDATE),4) + REPLACE(STR(DATEPART(MONTH, @FROMDATE), 2), ' ', '0') + REPLACE(STR(DATEPART(DAY, @FROMDATE), 2),     ' ', '0') AS DECIMAL(9,0))
SET @TO = CAST(STR(DATEPART(YEAR, @TODATE),4) + REPLACE(STR(DATEPART(MONTH, @TODATE), 2), ' ', '0') + REPLACE(STR(DATEPART(DAY, @TODATE), 2), ' ', '0') AS DECIMAL(9,0))

BEGIN
 --SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 --interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 --Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT 
UPH.TRANSDATE,
@from,
@to,
@FROMDATE,
@TODATE,
UPD.[EMPLOYEE] as 'UPCHKD.EMPLOYEE'
,UPD.EXPACCT AS 'UPCHKD.EXPACCT'
,SUBSTRING(UPD.EXPACCT, 6,2) LEXPACCT
,GL.ACCTFMTTD AS 'GLAMF.ACCTFMTTD'
,GL.ACCTDESC AS 'GLAMF.ACCTDESC'
,UPD.EARNDED AS 'UPCHKD.EARNDED'
,UPD.EARDEDTYPE AS 'UPCHKD.EARDEDTYPE'
,UPD.EEXTEND AS 'UPCHKD.EEXTEND'
,UPD.[HOURS] AS 'UPCHKD.HOURS'
,UPD.LINETYPE AS 'UPCHKD.LINETYPE'
,UPD.PEREND AS 'UPCHKD.PEREND'
,UPH.CHECKSTAT AS 'UPCHKH.CHECKSTAT'
,UPH.TRANSDATE AS 'UPCHKH.TRANSDATE'
,UPT.SHIFTACCT AS 'UPDIST.SHIFTACCT'
,UPE.FULLNAME AS 'UPEMPL.FULLNAME'
,UPD.[ENTRYSEQ] AS 'UPCHKD.ENTRYSEQ'


FROM [ISSDAT].[dbo].[UPCHKD] UPD
  LEFT JOIN [ISSDAT].[dbo].[GLAMF] GL ON UPD.EXPACCT = GL.ACCTFMTTD
  LEFT JOIN [ISSDAT].[dbo].[UPCHKH] UPH ON UPD.EMPLOYEE = UPH.EMPLOYEE AND      UPD.ENTRYSEQ = UPH.ENTRYSEQ AND UPD.PEREND = UPH.PEREND 
  LEFT JOIN [ISSDAT].[dbo].[UPEMPL] UPE ON UPE.EMPLOYEE = UPD.EMPLOYEE
  LEFT JOIN [ISSDAT].[dbo].[UPDTLM] UPM ON UPM.EARNDED = UPD.EARNDED
  LEFT JOIN [ISSDAT].[dbo].[UPDIST] UPT ON UPT.EARNDED = UPD.EARNDED AND UPT.EXPACCT = UPD.EXPACCT 
  where UPH.CHECKSTAT <> '4' AND UPH.TRANSDATE >= @FROM AND UPH.TRANSDATE < @TO 
  AND UPD.EEXTEND > 0.00 AND UPD.[HOURS] > 0.00 AND UPD.EXPACCT NOT LIKE '66400%' 
    AND substring(UPD.EXPACCT, 6,2) IN ('-1', '-2', '-3', '-4', '-5', '-6', '-7')
```